# How can I closed the property sheet dialog directly with my code?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying closed property sheet dialog directly in my code which created using OleCreatePropertyFrame API. for closing the dialog box  I am using PropSheet_PressButton API but i don't know the how to get handle for property sheet dialog.please if anyone know about this  suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

It does not really make sense to close a modal dialog if you don't control any of the code inside it.

You control the owner handle so that might be your best option; look for a enabled and visible window owned by your window. Perhaps `GetWindow(yourWindow, GW_ENABLEDPOPUP)` or `GetLastActivePopup`. This is slightly hacky of course but what you are doing is not normal.